# Curry lodash pick function doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, lodash, currying

I'm new to the Lodash curry function and I am struggling to figure out why **currying** some of the Lodash functions, like `pick`, doesn't work?

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
 
_.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
// works fine

_.curry(_.pick)(object)(['a', 'c']);
// => TypeError: _.curry(...)(...) is not a function
```

Why the second example doesn't have the same output as the first one? I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: Try this - _.curry(_.pick(object,(['a', 'c']))); hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it will work. But it loses the benefit of currying.

Comment: I want to first call the curried function with parameter "object" and then call the resulted function with the parameter "['a', 'c']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `_.curry()` can't infer the arity (number of params) needed by the `_.pick()` function. Add the arity of the `_.pick()` function (2) manually:

```js
const object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

const curriedPick = _.curry(_.pick, 2); // <- add the arity
 
console.log(curriedPick(object)(['a', 'c']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Greate, very clear explanation! I've also found out we can do `_.partial(_.pick, object)(['a','c'])`